# Any nice, animated mouse cursor themes?

Tags: mouse, themes, cursor, cursor-theme

Title says it all really, looking for some cursor themes with animation, any recommendations ?

14.04.2 with Unity

Comment: Have a look at `oneko` too ! It's fun !

Comment: Basic Animated Mouse Cursor using `CompizConfig Settings Manager` [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYy16_nTFbY)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Azenis.](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Azenis?content=165182) It's a animated one that's not too animated. You can find more at gnome-look.org and clicking on x11 cursor themes.

Comment: Very Nice one. Thanks! Do you know similar that goes well with dark gtk  theme?

Answer (score 1):

i use [Bibata Rainbow](https://www.pling.com/p/1445634) the small and beatuful cursor with color changing animation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to select any one you like [X11 Mouse Themes](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=36)

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work

Comment: @rahilwazir I believe gnome.org and gnome-look.org were receiving some sort of DOS attack or spam of some sort; so they now make you log in in order to view/download the content. However, what they have done is quite excessive

Answer (score 0):

I have installed [Polar Cursor Theme](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=27913) from KDE-look.org, a kind of minimalistic cursor theme with KDE touch. But I am using this cursor theme on Xubuntu for myself.

For the loading animation, the cursor changes to a spinning disc with a colored slit (orange, blue or green for choices), like slot screw drive.

I recommend this cursor theme for minimalists whom wanting to have cursor with beautiful KDE theme touch, minus the distraction (of bouncing cursor).